# Why is it when i ad 0 + 0 in my php, I receive undefined variable?

Tags: php, html, post

Hi guys I am doing this user calculation form and for some reason when I addition button 0 + 0 it gives me this error Notice: Undefined variable: add in /var/www/html/1018/5356684c357e7ff13ae21450a17d877d/Test-YT/index.php on line 44

other than that, it works good for all other numbers this is my php code

```
<html>
    <body>

        <style><?php include "style.css" ?></style>



        <form action="index.php" method="POST">

      <table border="1">

      <td>
        <p>insert value one: <input type="text" name="num1"> <br>
        <p>insert value two: <input type="text" name="num2"> <br>
      </td>

        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="add" value="Addition">
            <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Subtraction">
            <input type="submit" name="mult" value="Multiplication">
            <input type="submit" name="div" value="Division">
            <input type="submit" name="all" value="Display All">
        </td>
      </table>
        </form>



<div id="answers">


<?php

if (isset($_POST['num1']) && ($_POST['num2'])){
    $val1 = $_POST['num1'];
    $val2 = $_POST['num2']; 
    $add = $val1+$val2;
    $sub = $val1-$val2;
    $mult = $val1*$val2;
    $div = $val1/$val2; 
}

if (isset($_POST['add'])){
    echo $add;
}
else{
    echo "zero";
}

if (isset($_POST['sub'])){
    echo $sub;
}

if (isset($_POST['mult'])){
    echo $mult;
}

if (isset($_POST['div'])){
    echo $div;
}

if (isset($_POST['all'])){
    echo $add . "<br>" . $sub . "<br>" . $mult . "<br>" . $div . "<br>";
}

?>

</div>  

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST['num1']) && ($_POST['num2'])){
```

if `$_POST['num2']` is `0` this expression calculated to `false` and variable $add is not initialized, as other variables as well.

**edit:**
As suggested below, you probably wanted something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['num1']) && isset($_POST['num2'])) {
```

But also looks like you tried to prevent division by zero error. As a better solution, you can define all vars at first and also check non-zero value only before division.

```
$add = $sub = $mult = $div = 0; 
if (isset($_POST['num1']) && isset($_POST['num2'])){
    $val1 = $_POST['num1'];
    $val2 = $_POST['num2']; 
    $add = $val1+$val2;
    $sub = $val1-$val2;
    $mult = $val1*$val2;
    if ($val2) {
        $div = $val1/$val2; 
    }
}
```

So you can be sure script will not die even if `num1` and `num2` were not submitted.

Comment: +1, but you should speak the solution up too, as do `if (isset($_POST['num1']) && isset($_POST['num2'])){` instead or so..

Comment: Once that is fixed, there will be a dividing by zero error. Simply test for zero to avoid the error:
`$div = $val2==0?"Can't divide by zero":$val1/$val2;`